# secure connection from mobile device to application server

Tags: security, networking, mobile

I am after a little bit of help.

I have a mobile application that currently runs on both iOS and Android. this application uses in house APIs to do most of the back end work.

I have a need to start using some legacy services that sit within the back end servers in my company.

I have proposed that we use a new application server that will sit in the DMZ and this will run an application that will contact the services and get me the data i need.

My question is how can i ensure that the connection from the Mobile device to this application server is secure? what protocol should i use?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Application Server exposes an HTTP-based end-point which the Mobile app calls, then it can be secured by SSL. Based on the flavor of your Application Server, look into how to setup an SSL-endpoint and your mobile app can then talk to the SSL-enabled HTTP endpoint (HTTPS).

Comment: Thank you, that will do just fine :)

Comment: @AarronCaulton HTTPS highly secures your communication session; however, security is a more general topic. How will you guarantee that the requests are from the genuine app?